# Macbook Wi-Fi proxy settings not working

Tags: safari, proxy

When I configure my Macbook Pro M1 Pro (macOS 12.6) to use proxy settings all traffic which are not LAN/local stops working. I must use a proxy for getting access to the internet.

- I have tried via Safari/Chrome/Firefox. No other applications work either.
- We have the option of both authenticated and unauthenticated proxy but none of them works.
- Running `tcpdump` and trying to connect does not display any traffic on the proxy port.

However, setting `http_proxy`/`https_proxy` environment variables in the terminal and then `curl`ing Google works fine. I have tried setting the same settings as in the terminal in both the settings GUI and with the `networksetup` command in the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to not include http:// in the proxy url. You could think that it should have returned an error message about incorrect format.